# Add single quote to start and end of the vector of a string which would be fed into sqldf

Tags: r, string, paste, sqldf

I have vector of string like this:

```
vec1=letters[1:5] 
df=data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])
```

I want to subset this data frame by feeding in the string in SQL statement.

```
vec1=letters[1:5]
vec3=paste("'", paste(vec1, collapse = "','"), "'", sep = '')
p=paste("select * from df where b in (", vec3, ")")
sqldf(p)
```

This works well but is there any elegant way to do this task. I tried with `squotes` too but it doesn't gives me the desired single quote.

```
vec3=paste(vec1, collapse = "','")
vec3=sQuote(vec3)
```

Comment: `DBI::dbQuoteString(conn, vec1)`?

Comment: @r2evans The question is not related to a DBI. I would just like to create a sting.

Comment: Then what's wrong with `paste(sQuote(vec1), collapse = ",")`?

Comment: This wont work with sqldf. I would like to get ' around my string so that it is sql compliant.

Comment: `paste0("select * from df where b in (", toString(sQuote(vec1)), ")")`?

Comment: I think sqldf wont take ‘a’ style of quotes. It has to be like this 'a'.

Comment: what about `sprintf("'%s'", paste(vec1, collapse = "','"))`. Could be put into a function to make it more elegant.

Comment: @drmariod: That worked out well. Pls post it as an anwser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` for this.

```
sprintf("'%s'", paste(vec1, collapse = "','"))
```

create a function will make it more readable...

```
addQuotes <- function(x) sprintf("'%s'", paste(x, collapse = "','"))
addQuotes(vec1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The sqldf package loads the gsubfn package providing `fn` for this purpose.  `fn` supports backtick and dollar substitutions for code and single variables respectively.  For example, try any of these.  See `?fn` and the examples on the sqldf github page.

```
fn$sqldf("select * from df where b in ( `toString(shQuote(vec1, 'sh'))` ) ")

p <- fn$identity("select * from df where b in ( `toString(shQuote(vec1, 'sh'))` ) ")
sqldf(p)

s <- toString(shQuote(vec1, 'sh'))
p <- fn$identity("select * from df where b in ( $s ) ")
sqldf(p)
```

Comment: Thanks for these useful functions. For the sake of completeness this could also be done by `sqldf(paste("select * from df where b in (",toString(shQuote(vec1, 'sh')),")", sep = ''))
`.

Comment: Possible but a big mess and not desirable.